# Не создается параметризованный url по id

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-orm

Создал модель `Colors`, зарегистрировал в админке, позже создал несколько строк с названиями цветов. К каждому цвету подставлены свои `id`, но когда перехожу по `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blocks/1/` выдет ошибку

```
Using the URLconf defined in myFirstApp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    admin/
    bboard/
    blocks/
    blocks/ <int:color_id>
The current path, blocks/1/, didn't match any of these
```

Хотя я проверил, и id под номером 1 соответствует красный цвет

```
>>> c = Color.objects.get(id=1)
>>> c
<Color: red>
```

Но когда вызываю другие страницы начиная с id == 2 , страница грузится удачно.

файл models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Blocks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя блока')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    blocks_color = models.ForeignKey('Color', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, verbose_name='цвет блока')


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Блок"
        verbose_name_plural = "Блоки"
        ordering = ['name']

class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Цвет', db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Цвет'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Цвета'
        ordering = ['color']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color
```

Файл admin.py

```
from .models import Blocks, Color

class BlocksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'blocks_color')
    list_display_link = ('name', 'description')
    search_field = ('name', )

class ColorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('color',)
    list_display_link = ('color',)
    search_field = ('color', )

admin.site.register(Blocks, BlocksAdmin)
admin.site.register(Color, ColorAdmin)
```

файл urls.py, основного проекта

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('bboard/', include('bboard.urls')),
    path('blocks/', include('blocks.urls')),
]
```

файл urls.py, приложения blocks

```
from .views import index, by_color



urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('<int:color_id>', by_color),
]
```

файл views.py

```
from .models import Blocks, Color


def index(request):
    blocks = Blocks.objects.all()
    colors = Color.objects.all()
    context =  {'blocks':blocks, 'colors':colors}
    return render(request, 'blocks/index.html',context)

def by_color(request, color_id):
    colors = Color.objects.all()
    current_color = Color.objects.get(pk=color_id)
    blocks = Blocks.objects.filter(blocks_color=color_id)
    context = {'colors':colors, 'blocks':blocks, 'current_color': current_color}
    return render(request, 'blocks/by_color.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В urls.py уровня приложения попробуйте добавить слеш:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('<int:color_id>/', by_color),
]
```

Comment: Могу ли узнать, почему не срабатывало именно с единицей?

Comment: Честно говоря не знаю) я думал это что-то на уровне сервера, то есть сервер получая запрос без слеша редиректит его на адрес со слешем, но что странно, если покидать Get запросы через например Postman, то все работает и без **/** . Скорее всего я не прав. Очень многие утверждают, что слешы в конце пути обязательны, в документации Джанги тоже везде так https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request